# Creating a new string containing a previously declared string var

Tags: c

I want to do something like looks like this (obviously not valid c code, though):

```
char test[] = "you";
char new[] = "hey %s over there", test; // Want to get back "hey you over there"
```

Here's my way, but it seems too complicated. Get the len of both the test and new, create a new string buffer that can hold both lengths, concatenate new and test to the string buffer. Is there a better way to do this?

Also `char hi[] = "hi"` vs `char *hi = "hi"`. What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's the time-honored traditional way of doing it in C, though I think you meant the length of `test` and the string literal since `new` doesn't have a length until you write the data into it.

And, as an aside, if you *ever* expect that your code will be used in a C++ compiler, please don't call your variables `new` :-) Although I'm assuming that was just a quick and dirty code sample since `new` isn't a good descriptive name for a variable anyway (`newString`, or something similar, would be better).

If you're likely to be doing it a lot, there's no problem with writing a helper function that does all the grunt work for you. That may make your code look cleaner but I'd simply go for your current solution using `strcpy/strcat/strlen/sprintf` et al.

Or, you can use a third-party piece of code like [the better string library](http://bstring.sourceforge.net/), licences and management attitudes permitting (the licences are BSD/GPL but management can still sometimes be a problem).

It has the advantage of not dragging in a lot of extraneous functionality as some third-party libraries are wont to do. All it does is the string handling.

---

As to the difference between these two:

```
char hi[] = "hi";
char *hi = "hi";
```

the first gives you a modifiable character array and the latter does not (try `hi[0] = 'a';` in both cases, doing so with the latter would be undefined behaviour). The latter also allows you to change the value of the `hi` pointer to point somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sprintf function.

```
int main(int ac, char** argv)                                                   
{
  char test[] = "you";
  char new[] = "hey %s over there";
  char* total;

  int len = strlen(test) + strlen(new) + 1;
  total = malloc(len);
  total[len - 1] = '\0';
  sprintf(total, new, test);
  printf(total);
  free(total);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `snprintf` to do the actual string formatting, but you need to compute the size manually:

```
char newstring[19];
snprintf(newstring, 19, "hey %s over there", test);
```

Note that you can't really have a constant-sized array if you want to compute the constituent string lengths dynamically (i.e. there's no "constant expression" that can go in place of `19` other than some actual constant). Either you accept C99's variable-length arrays, or you allocate dynamic memory:

```
char * newstring = malloc(computed_size_of_new_string);
```

Another alternative is to allocate some large, static buffer, `char newstring[2048];`, and then check the result of `snprintf` to see if truncation occurred.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's how it works in C. Oh, and don't forget to allocate one byte for the terminating `'\0'`.

There are a bunch of libraries who handle strings in a more comfortable way though.